# Adding a reference for specific platform on multi-platform project

Tags: c#, .net, multitargeting

Trying to figure out to use `System.Diagnostics.EventLog` in a multi-target project. The targets are:

- .NET 5
- .NET Framework 4.8

I have 3 projects in my solution and everything works fine on the 2 others.
The one raising up problems is referencing `System.Diagnostics.EventLog` for **.NET 5** since it's required to use `EventLog`.
On the **.NET framework 4.8**, `System.Diagnostics.EventLog` namespace uses `System.dll`.

I'm looking for a way to include a reference to this library only in **.NET 5** project, and not in the **4.8** one.

When I ad the reference to the project, it seems like it adds it to both targets. Is there a way to add it to the **.NET 5** and not to the **.NET framework 4.8**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aftfer many tries, seek and (almost) destroy, I finally realized it was really simple:

Editing the project file and giving a conditional compilation argument on the reference which was required only for the **.NET 5** target:

```
<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net5.0-windows' ">
  <Reference Include="System.Diagnostics.EventLog">
    <HintPath>C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Diagnostics.EventLog.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

That's it!